# NuGet Versioning Auto Increment Pre-Release

Tags: svn, nuget, versioning, auto-increment

We have 3 hosted source control management repositories (subversion) and 3 NuGet repositories for each environment:

- development
- qa
- trunk

Code:

- Library X      (version 1.0.0)
- Application A

I have set-up a post build event on Library X to create the NuGet package and push it to the development repository.  Because these changes are not yet stable, I want these packages to be pre-release packages.

From my understanding and reading, I should follow the format of X.1.0.1-alpha001. I've included the version number in the AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.1-alpha001")]
```

My problem is that I have no idea on how to auto-increment this value from 001 to 002.  I also do not know how to auto increment these within my CI server Jenkins.  I want to make this as seamless as possible for the developers.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a .targets files for your solution, which can be configured to increment the AssemblyInformationalVersion each build.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx

Comment: I am new to the .targets files and am playing around with them.  Not sure exactly how do update the AssemblyInformationVersion within the .targets file.  Would you be able to provide some sample code?